# Integral of $\frac{1}{A\cos(2x+B)+C}$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{A\cos(2x+B)+C}\text{d}x$$
Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: "Solve" is not the right word here.  "Evaluate" would fit.  "Solve" and "equation" are words that get used as catch-alls by students who haven't learned definitions.

Comment: If $A$ and $C$ are such that $\{x \in [0,2\pi]:\ A\cos x+C=0\}\ne \emptyset$, then your integral diverges.

Comment: Yes, you don't "solve" integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First notice that since $\cos$ is periodic, and you're integrating over (twice) its period, the $+B$ doesn't make a difference, and so
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{A\cos(2x+B)+C}\, dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{A\cos 2x + C}\, dx$$
At this point, a [$t$-substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)* should do the trick $-$ put $t=\tan x$, so that $\cos 2x = \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and so forth.

(*Thanks Michael Hardy)

Comment: [Here is a better link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) for that substitution.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Cheers, I thought I'd seen something better.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer!